# Right channel minus left channel?

Tags: voice, audio, audacity

I have music with voice on left channel and just music on right (WAV 16 bit).
I want to distinguish ONLY VOICE from file.
I think it's some like left channel - right channel = voice, but i don't know how to do this?
I have audacity program to edit music files. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have voice on left and music on right, then just use the left channel. This isn't on topic here though so I'll migrate to Sound Design.

Answer (score 2):

With [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) on the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i ${f} -filter_complex "[0:0]pan=1c|c0 = 0.5 * c0 + -0.5 * c1[side]" -map "[side]" ${f}_voiceonly.wav
```

Where `${f}` is the file you want to convert.

You can also do it with any DAW: either use an L/R→M/S matrix and balance to the right, or just explode the file to two tracks and inverse the polarity on one of them. Should even be possible in Audacity, but likely you'll be easier off with ffmpeg then... try [Reaper](http://reaper.fm/) if you want something powerful yet easy with GUI.